# When does it become more practical to use a variable rather than resolve an equation in terms of efficiency

Tags: javascript

I was wondering which option would be faster for a program I need to optimize (example given below). 
Would it be more efficient to store a variable as the answer to an equation, or resolve the equation each time the problem is requested?

Example A

```
function(a,b){
return [a+b, //a+b is representing a more complicated math problem
a+b+1, 
a+b+2]
}
```

or

Example B

```
function(a,b){
var x = a+b
return [x,x+1,x+2]
}
```

I know that it would not make much of a difference here, but in a larger project, I would really like to use the most efficient route.

Comment: You're falling victim to premature optimization.

Comment: @JosephSible In terms of efficiency yes. However this sort of "optimization" good in terms of readability

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment instead of an answer because it doesn't answer your direct question and also because I think you're asking the wrong question. When coding, always think in terms of debugging. If you need to change the algorithm in the future does it make more sense to change "a+b" in a dozen places or change how "x" is calculated in only one place?

Comment: I don't know much about performance, so I guess the second one would _technically_ be faster, since it performs the computation once? I imagine V8 (and other engines) would optimize it away, though. But either way, yeah, premature opt. Profile, figure out if this is actually a bottleneck, then address it then.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the comments on this question. I would write this answer as an opinion rather than a hard and a fast rule.
I feel this is more important in terms of readability and maintainability of codebase in log run. It's one of the basic principles of development to write DRY code, which not only helps us maintain the code but in turn end up optimising it as well.
To answer your question - I feel you should do it whenever you see a chance in a code which you are planning to push to production. However, if its more of a POC I'll leave that to you to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Example C should be a tiny bit faster as less parsing, and less variables :

```
function(a, b) {
    return [a = a + b, a + 1, a + 2]
}
```

But Example B is more readable